# Integrated zxing and scan on demand

Tags: android, zxing

I integrated qr code scanning feature in my app using zxing source code as a **library**. My activity extended Capture Activity and override handleDecode method of Capture Activity class.
My code inside override method handleDecode looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode){
String result = rawResult.getText();
if(result==WRONG_CODE){
      //do nothing
}else if(result==RIGHT_CODE){
      //do something
   }
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. If the user scan correct code then do something, otherwise keep scanning until obtain the correct code. However, the problem is that zxing scanner only scan once. If the qr code returned is wrong, user has to restart the activity in order for the scanner to scan again.

I tried something like this if the result code is wrong but it doesn't work.

```
Hanlder handler = new Handler();
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.preview_id, CaptureActivity.BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself today, but solved it by calling getHandler() instead of creating a new handler when doing sendEmptyMessageDelayed. Old question, so I suppose this won't be helping you at all, but for others with the same problem.. well, here's the solution:

```
   @Override 
   public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor) {    
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Scanned code " + rawResult.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
        getHandler().sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview, 1000L);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not

```
new Handler()
```

Not

```
getHandler()
```

In your `CaptureActivity`, there should be a `CaptureActivityHandler`. Use that handler to send the message.